# <pm:view> Tag Library error

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I try to create a mobile application with primefaces 5.0 /JSF. Does anyone knows and solve the problem with `<pm:view>` tag?

Maven:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
 <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
 <version>5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Error:

```
An Error Occurred:

/test.xhtml @9,28 <pm:view> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/mobile, but no tag was defined for name: view
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of `pm:view` seems to have disappeared with PrimeFames 5.0.
Refer to the mobile section of the PrimeFaces user guide 5.0 or [5.1](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_1.pdf), not to the PrimeFaces-mobile user guide 0.9.4.